# Mixing asp.net web site with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am having an asp.net web site and in that in the app_Code folder I have created a folder call Areas and Created CommonEOS Area and  added the MVC controller,views and models to it.

In the controller I get the error cannot resolve index for the view

How To solve this.
The controller code is

```
Function About() As ActionResult
 Return View() //<== I get cannot resolve here.
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this approach for the views locator:

[A Custom View Engine with Dynamic View Location](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should have your views in the `Views` folder if you to follow MVC conventions. You can also create an `Area`, but you should follow the conventions for creating Areas (registering, etc) or take advantage of the tooling to create new areas.

If you don't want to follow convention, you must explicitly tell MVC where to find the view.

Comment: My folder structure is like this - inside App_code              Area/CommonEOS/Controllers    Is there any way to register the Area Folder I have code to regiester commonEos

Comment: In the q you said that you created the Area in the app_code folder. That's not standard